# Change the image of a label from radio input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the label images by input of a radio button with JavaScript or CSS.

I've tried `"input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label"` within CSS and
also tried to change it by JavaScript.

What I currently have:

```js
var service1 = document.getElementById('service1');
var service2 = document.getElementById('service2');
var service3 = document.getElementById('service3');

if(service1 == document.getElementById('service1').checked){
 document.getElementById('service2').src = "decent_rate_unchecked.png";
 document.getElementById('service3').src = "good_rate_unchecked.png";
}else if(service2 == document.getElementById('service2').checked){
 document.getElementById('service1').src = "bad_rate_unchecked.png";
 document.getElementById('service3').src = "good_rate_unchecked.png";
}else{
 document.getElementById('service2').src = "bad_rate_unchecked.png";
 document.getElementById('service3').src = "decent_rate_unchecked.png";
}
```

```css
#service1 input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + label{
 border: 5px solid black;
 border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<form action="Sources/form.php" method="post" id="container">
<label id="service">
<input type="radio" checked="checked" id="service1" name="service" value="1" required="required"/>
<label for="service1">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/1/" style="width:42px;height:42px;" for="service1" title="bad"/>
</label>
<input type="radio" id="service2" name="service" value="5,5" required="required"/>
<label for="service2">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/1/" style="width:42px;height:42px;" for="service2" title="decent"/>
</label>
<input type="radio" id="service3" name="service" value="10" required="required"/>
<label for="service3">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/1/" style="width:42px;height:42px;" for="service3" title="good"/>
</label>
</form>
```

Expected result would be that the images change into the pre-made "unchecked" states of the images, actual results is that nothing happens except for the fact that it gets a black round border if it's selected

Comment: Try `if(service1.checked)`. You should test your code in the Developer Tools Console: `document.getElementById('service1').checked` should return a `boolean`. Although `service1`, which is an `HTMLElement` will never be equal to a `boolean`

Comment: Locally hosted images aren't going to work to great here.

Comment: For the images, you could use: `http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/1/`, `http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/2/`, `http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/3/`

Comment: CSS is badly formed. `#service1 input[type="radio"]` should just be `#service1` since they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need js here, I see a lot of issues with HTML markup attributes, but to solve your problem just use this code,

```css
form.service__rate label{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}

#service1 + label{
/*background: url("./Sources/bad-rate.png") center/cover no-repeat;*/
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/1/") center/cover no-repeat;
}
#service2 + label{
/*background: url("./Sources/decent-rate.png") center/cover no-repeat;*/
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/1/") center/cover no-repeat;
}
#service3 + label{
/*background: url("./Sources/good-rate.png") center/cover no-repeat;*/
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/1/") center/cover no-repeat;
}

#service1:checked + label {
/*background: url("./Sources/bad_rate_unchecked.png") center/cover no-repeat;*/
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/2/") center/cover no-repeat;
}
#service2:checked + label {
/*background: url("./Sources/decent_rate_unchecked.png") center/cover no-repeat;*/
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/2/") center/cover no-repeat;
}
#service3:checked + label {
/*background: url("./Sources/good_rate_unchecked.png") center/cover no-repeat;*/
background: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/technics/2/") center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<form action="Sources/form.php" method="post" id="container" class="service__rate">
<fieldset>
  <legend>Service rate:</legend>
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="service1" name="service" value="1" required="required"/>
  <label for="service1">
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="service2" name="service" value="5,5" required="required"/>
  <label for="service2">
  </label>
  <input type="radio" id="service3" name="service" value="10" required="required"/>
  <label for="service3">
</label>
</fieldset>
</form>
```